# Synaptic won't start after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, synaptic

I've Ubuntu 12.04 (upgrade) in my notebook (axioo m12cw)...i tried to install synaptic package manager,but it won't start since upgrading to 12.04..but if i using Ubuntu software center,it's run normally..how to run synaptic run normally??

Comment: Run it from a terminal (just type synaptic and hit enter - and ignore the warning about not having admin priviledges) and copy and paste any output/errors back here that appear in the terminal as it tries to run.

Comment: you will need to use "sudo synaptic" in order to be able to make changes, otherwise, synaptic will only allow you to see and choose your software selection but you won't be allowed to make any changes. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that's why I said to ignore the warning as it is only to test why it won't start.  Normally the user should run it from dash or somewhere graphically and it will run gksudo automatically first.  I didn't want to confuse things with sudo'ing from the command line.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo [`gksudo synaptic`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) is preferable to `sudo synaptic`.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix it by following this steps:

1. Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute this command:

   `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop`
2. With the file open, change find this line:

   ```
     Exec=synaptic-pkexec
   ```

   And change it to:

   ```
     Exec=gksudo synaptic
   ```
3. Save file and close the text editor.